# Android Notification: add typeface for title and content

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-typeface

I'm trying to add a `Typeface` in my `NotificationCompat.Builder`  ->`setContentTitle()` and `setContentText()`. I initialized `Typeface` by

```
Typeface banglaFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "kalpurush.ttf");
```

in `IntentService`. To create `Notification` i used following code.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(userName)

                .setAutoCancel(true)
                // .setStyle(
                // new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle())
                .setVibrate(pattern).setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500)
                .setSound(alarmSound).setContentText(msg);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        Notification n = mBuilder.build();

        int min = 1001;
        int max = 2000;

        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        int notID = randomNumber;
        mNotificationManager.notify(notID, n);
```

But i cann't understand how can i set the `Typeface` in my `Notification` title and content. Any suggestions or reference would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the font of any notifications broadcast by the system is largely determined by the preferred font selected by the user in their settings meaning that your font will be ignored.

Comment: This is not possible, and any hack might break anytime on different device/update

Comment: Notifications contain textViews and you can always setTypeface on textViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very useful answer, done by creating own typefacespan http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/567126/AndroidplusNotificationplusinplusotherpluslanguage

> **EDIT:**

custom_notification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/custom_notification"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/notification_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/notification_text"
    style="@style/NotificationText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notification_image"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

code for android to notification method

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context,
        SpannableStringBuilder message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    // create new id
    Date date = new Date();
    int notificationid = (int) date.getTime();
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            notificationid, notificationIntent, 0);
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context
            .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
            R.layout.custom_notification);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_image,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    // contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title,
    // "My custom notification title");
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, message);
    notification.contentView = contentView;
    notification.contentIntent = intent;
    // notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(notificationid, notification);
}
```

call this method like this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("মুখ্যমন্ত্রী হওয়ার পর থেকেই রাজ্যের হাতে আরও বেশি ক্ষমতা 4দেওয়ার দাবিতে বারেবারে সরব হয়েছেন তিনি");
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "kalpurush.ttf");
sb.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, sb.length() - 1,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
generateNotification(context, sb);
```

> **UPDATE:**

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

    private final Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        newType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

i hope this is very helpful

Comment: please create a custom view using remoteviews and then set this SpannableStringBuilder to content text. it worked for me.

Comment: Where is CustomTypefaceSpan.class

Comment: @Sudo use the link in the answer for CustomTypefaceSpan class

Comment: @amrut-bidri I added your code but it working on Android 4.4 and Android 5 but not working on 2.3 can you give any help i downloaded your font and tried with your hind word but its also not working on 2.3 devices.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to set typeface on notification is convert text as Bitmap and Render in the canvas.for render custom notification we want to use remoteview.

```
custome_notification.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/notification_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>




public void showCustomNotifications(Context context, String text){
   DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
   int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;


   Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width - 72, 84, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
   Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
   Paint paint =  new Paint();
   Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getResources().getString(R.string.sinhalaFont));
   paint.setAntiAlias(true);
   paint.setSubpixelText(true);
   paint.setTypeface(font2);
   paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
   //paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   paint.setTextSize(50);
   paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
   myCanvas.drawText(text, 80, 60, paint);



   int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
   // create new id
   Date date = new Date();
   int notificationid = (int) date.getTime();
   long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Anynews", when);
   //String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
   Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
   // set intent so it does not start a new activity
   notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
   PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
        notificationid, notificationIntent, 0);
   RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.custom_notification);
   contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notification_img,
        myBitmap);
   // contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title,
   // "My custom notification title");
   //contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, message);
   notification.contentView = contentView;
   notification.contentIntent = intent;
   // notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
   notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   notificationManager.notify(notificationid, notification);
}
```